# Image manipulation in Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, computer-vision

This is a bit of a naive question, but I'm new to data science, thus the question.
I'm following a course which reads a 2D image and performs the following operation,

```
image = mpimg.imread('test.jpg')
duplicate = np.copy(image)
red_threshold = green_threshold = blue_threshold = 0
rgb_threshold = [red_threshold, green_threshold, blue_threshold]
```

Specifically this line

```
thresholds = (image[:,:,0] < rgb_threshold[0]) | (image[:,:,1] < rgb_threshold[1]) | (image[:,:,2] < rgb_threshold[2])
duplicate[thresholds] = [0,0,0]
```

The explanation for this line of code is,

> The result, duplicate, is an image in which pixels that were above the
>   threshold have been retained, and pixels below the threshold have been
>   blacked out.

I just don't understand how?
Can someone break this up a little and help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: I would suggest using a minimal representative data and running the posted code and further study each part of `|` separately.

Comment: This is not a 3D image, it is a 2D image with 3 channels. Some software represents such an image as a 3D matrix, but that doesn't make it a 3D image.

Comment: @CrisLuengo edited and corrected.

Comment: Anyway the example seems to me a bit buggy, where did you copypaste it from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above expression,

```
thresholds = (image[:,:,0] < rgb_threshold[0]) | (image[:,:,1] < rgb_threshold[1]) | (image[:,:,2] < rgb_threshold[2])
```

unfolded:

```
image[:,:,0]
```

here the 3rd index, 0 is the channel of the image from **RGB**, thus `image[:,:,0], image[:,:,1], image[:,:,2]` is **RGB channel**s' pixels respectively.

```
image[:,:,0] < rgb_threshold[0])
```

means, that we only need pixels with are below the value of the actual channel's **threshold** value, here 0.

In this case we intend get the sum of numpy arrays of the thresholded color channels's values with [bitwise or](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) operator `|` like e.g:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([26,0,46,])
b = np.array([0,55,1,])

print(a | b)
```

**Out:**

```
[26 55 47]
```